# How can I generate array (for each row) using faker?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I want to generate an array like this for every row:

[image]

Previously I used:

```
randomElement($array = array ("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"))
```

but it generates 1 string for 1 row; I want to generate several string in 1 row.

Answer (score 3):

If you check [the Faker documentation](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker), there's also a `randomElements` function.

```
randomElements($array = array ('a','b','c'), $count = 1)
```

For some bonus randomness, use something like `numberBetween(1, count($array))` for the `$count`.